# classicthesis and enumitem: description list won't compile if pdfspacing option is not specified

Tags: errors, enumitem, classicthesis, description

This code won't compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[hello] Hi
\item[what] why
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Here is the relevant part of the log:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.   } l.8
>   \item[hello]
>                  Hi A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up`weird
>   error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

The following code instead compile without errors:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[hello] Hi
\item[what] why
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Is this a classicthesis bug?

I have miktex-tex-bin 3.14159265
classicthesis 4.2
enumitem 3.5.2
koma-script 3.24

Comment: What does this have to do with enumitem? The .log is about a font which doesn't have smallcaps.

Comment: That is a warning. The error is "missing number treated as zero". I have no problem with smallcaps in chapters and sections headers. So how to fix the problem other that `pdfspacing` option?

Comment: Also it was falling back to the "normal" font, and forcing the fallback with `\DeclareFontShape{TU}{pplj}{m}{sc} { <-> ssub * pplj/m/n }{}` isolated the error. I am removing that part of the log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not really a bug (although the code could be better) just two packages redefining the same thing (description label formatting) and tripping over each other.

`classicthesis` defines the description label format

```
% descriptionlabels
   \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
   \hspace*{\labelsep}\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}} % spacedlowsmallcaps textit textsc
```

Where `\spacedlowsmallcaps` is from `soul` and is expecting a list of characters `hello` in your example.

But `enumitem` adds formatting hooks at that point (because that's what the package is designed to do) so `#1` is

```
\enit@align {\enit@format {hello}}
```

so when `soul` tries to step through each token it sees `\enit@align` rather than `h`.

The `pdfspacing` option tells `classicthesis` to use `microtype` rather than `soul` for letterspacing, which seems a reasonable workaround in this case.

Comment: I always wondered why Latex does not give errors or at least warnigs in those cases, like e.g. C does when you define 2 functions with the same name. Do you ny any chance now where enumitem set the hooks?

Comment: @raffamaiden is a macro processor it has almost no information about the body of a definition it's not like a compiled function compare it to the C pre-processor, not to C.

Comment: @raffamaiden also in this case where would you want a warning? the `description` environment is already defined by the class. `classicthesis redefines it` (presumably you don't want to be warned) and `enumitem` redefines it (you presumably don't want to be warned) the fact that these two definitions cause a third package, soul, to get handed data it can't handle is just unfortunate. classicthesis could detect enumitem and use its hooks to customise the lists rather than patch them directly but you can't expect a package author to test for every other package, ctan has thousands of packages.

Comment: Well something like "description environment for re-defined for the second time" would definitely be better for me than "missing number treated as zero". Thanks for the answer anyway. Do you still know where enumitem doe the hook? Just to improve my learning of the language

Comment: @raffamaiden they just define different parts of latex list internals which don't then work together. Hard to answer your question about enumitem, adding hooks so that list formatting can be parameterised without needing low level patches as done by classicthesis is the whole point of the package `\enit@align` appears in 22 lines but here for `description` I suppose mostly the definition at line 1283 `\def\makelabel##1...`